# Can the breaking of a steel cable be considered as a crackling noise?

Tags: forces, scale-invariance

How strange are the ways for finding questions! I was searching for some information on the topic of topological quantum field theory (a question was asked in this context), which directed me to the subjects of d-forms and symplectic geometry, via which I went further to the van der Pol oscillator and chaotic behavior, to end up in the subject of [crackling noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crackling_noise) phenomena. In the article, one can read:

> Crackling noise arises when a system is subject to an external force and it responds via events that appear very similar at many different scales. In a classical system, there are usually two states, on and off. However, sometimes a state can exist in between. There are three main categories this noise can be sorted into: the first is popping where events at very similar magnitude occur continuously and randomly, e.g. popcorn; the second is snapping where there is little change in the system until a critical threshold is surpassed, at which point the whole system flips from one state to another, e.g. snapping a pencil; the third is crackling which is a combination of popping and snapping, where there are some small and some large events with a relation law predicting their occurrences, referred to as universality.[2] Crackling can be observed in many natural phenomena, e.g. crumpling paper,[2] fire, occurrences of earthquakes, and the magnetization of magnets.

For example, when magnetizing an iron bar, it was discovered (in 1910, well before the arrival of real quantum mechanics!) that the building up of the H-field didn't increase continuously, but instead, at first little domains in the iron grow in steps, (each time a magnetic dipole, or more, flip; each individual flip case is called a pop).
Before the whole little domain is magnetized in steps, the collection of not yet popped individual atomic magnetic moments in the little domains start to build up the magnetization of bigger domains by all popping at once (in effect they act as a bigger pop than the pop of a single atom) in the right state.
So the magnetization in the bigger domain is built up in the same discrete, non-continuous way as is the case in the smallest domain. Then, again, bigger domains are magnetized, built up again in the same way as the preceding domain, but with bigger pops. This process ends when the domains are that big to make the whole iron bar, magnetized. Obviously, also this last process isn't a continuous one: in this last process, the biggest pops (corresponding to the highest number of not yet flipped atoms flipping simultaneously) proceeds in discontinuous steps. The biggest pops in these domains proceed just like the pops in the smallest domain, only now no bigger domains can be formed.

It's clear that this is ** a system subject to an external force and it responds via events that appear very similar at many different scales**. Just like the sound I hear when squeezing my bag of potato chips.

But then I started wondering and asked myself the same process of the crackling noise is going on in a (particular) steel cable when it "snaps". Snapping is also called in the article but I have my doubts that this steel cable example is a case of snapping.

The steel cable I assume to be made out of equally thin steel threads. A number of these thin threads are used to form a small-thickness cable, after which these are used to form a new cable to form a thicker one, after which...etc. until the cable has the desired thickness.
When a maximum force is applied to the cable, will, after individual snappings occur in the basic steel threads, the smallest sub cables will "give up" first after which the next (thicker) sub cable gives up, and so on until the whole cable gives up?

While in this case, snapping is involved, contrary to the iron bar magnetization example (where popping is involved), does the process of the steel cable giving up is an example of crackling noise too?

Comment: What is the question actually? There is a fair bit of discussion of this phenomenon in Sornette's "Critical phenomena in natural science".

Comment: I can imagine that you might be able to model the process of a snapping cable similarly to models of rupture/slip in earthquake faults or granular materials, such as in [earth.usc.edu/~ybz/pubs_recent/BZ_etal_P11/Ben-Zion_etal_P11.pdf, www.nature.com/articles/nphys1957/]. e.g., each thread has its own yield stress & when one snaps it redistributes its stress to neighboring cables until there is a catastrophic event and the entire cable snaps. However, whether the statistics of these events actually have a roughly scale-invariant distribution would ultimately be an experimental question.